# Prove: $\sin(v) = \frac{z - \bar{z}}{2|z|i}$, where $\arg(z) = v$

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers

I am currently stuck on a problem involving trigonometric functions and complex numbers, and I was hoping someone could help me out.

The problem states that I need to prove the equation:

$$\sin(v) = \frac{z - \bar{z}}{2|z|i} \qquad \text{if} \qquad \arg(z) = v$$

Here is what I have attempted so far:

Let $z = |z|e^{iv}$, then $\bar{z} = |z|e^{-iv}$.
Substituting these values into the equation gives:

$$\sin(v) = \frac{|z|e^{iv} - |z|e^{-iv}}{2|z|i}$$

Simplifying this expression, I get:

$$\sin(v) = \frac{e^{iv} - e^{-iv}}{2i}$$

From here, I am not sure how to proceed. I've tried using the identity $\sin(x) = \frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i}$,

but I'm not sure if that is applicable in this case.

I would greatly appreciate any help or suggestions on how to continue from here.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Other than the fact that this argument essentially runs in reverse, the equations look good.

Answer (score 4):

Start from the RHS

$$\frac{z - \bar{z}}{2|z|i}=\frac{|z|e^{iv} - |z|e^{-iv}}{2|z|i}=\frac{e^{iv} - e^{-iv}}{2i}=\frac{\cos v+i\sin v-(\cos v-i\sin v)}{2i}=\sin v$$

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to prove that. I'll just show you two ways.

For this we need the following formulas:

- Euler's Formula ($1$): $e^{x \cdot i} = \cos\left( x \right) + \sin\left( x \right) \cdot i$
- According to Euler's Formula ($2$): $z = \left| z \right| \cdot
     e^{\arg\left( z \right) \cdot i} \Leftrightarrow \arg\left( z \right) = -\ln\left( \frac{z}{\left| z \right|} \right) \cdot i$
- Consequence of Euler's Formula ($3$): $\sin\left( z \right) = \frac{e^{z \cdot i} - e^{-z \cdot i}}{2 \cdot i}$
- Argument of Conjugate Formula ($4$): $\arg\left( \bar{z} \right) = -\arg\left( z \right)$

##### Startig With The LHS

Wit thisn wi'll get:
$$
\begin{align*}
\sin\left( v \right) &= \frac{z - \bar{z}}{2 \cdot \left| z \right| \cdot i}\\
\sin\left( \arg\left( z \right) \right) &= \frac{z - \bar{z}}{2 \cdot \left| z \right| \cdot i} \quad\mid\quad \text{Formula}\, 3\\
\frac{e^{\arg\left( z \right) \cdot i} - e^{-\arg\left( z \right) \cdot i}}{2 \cdot i} &= \frac{z - \bar{z}}{2 \cdot \left| z \right| \cdot i} \quad\mid\quad \text{Formula}\, 2\\
\frac{e^{-\ln\left( \frac{z}{\left| z \right|} \right) \cdot i \cdot i} - e^{--\ln\left( \frac{z}{\left| z \right|} \right) \cdot i \cdot i}}{2 \cdot i} &= \frac{z - \bar{z}}{2 \cdot \left| z \right| \cdot i}\\
\frac{e^{-\ln\left( \frac{z}{\left| z \right|} \right) \cdot (-1)} - e^{+\ln\left( \frac{z}{\left| z \right|} \right) \cdot (-1)}}{2 \cdot i} &= \frac{z - \bar{z}}{2 \cdot \left| z \right| \cdot i}\\
\frac{e^{\ln\left( \frac{z}{\left| z \right|} \right)} - e^{-\ln\left( \frac{z}{\left| z \right|} \right)}}{2 \cdot i} &= \frac{z - \bar{z}}{2 \cdot \left| z \right| \cdot i}\\
\frac{e^{\ln\left( \frac{z}{\left| z \right|} \right)} - e^{\ln\left( \left( \frac{z}{\left| z \right|}  \right)^{-1} \right)}}{2 \cdot i} &= \frac{z - \bar{z}}{2 \cdot \left| z \right| \cdot i}\\
\frac{\frac{z}{\left| z \right|} - \left( \frac{z}{\left| z \right|}  \right)^{-1}}{2 \cdot i} &= \frac{z - \bar{z}}{2 \cdot \left| z \right| \cdot i}\\
\frac{\frac{z}{\left| z \right|} - \frac{\left| z \right|}{z}}{2 \cdot i} &= \frac{z - \bar{z}}{2 \cdot \left| z \right| \cdot i}\\
\frac{\frac{z}{\left| z \right|} - \frac{\left| z \right| \cdot \bar{z}}{z \cdot \bar{z}}}{2 \cdot i} &= \frac{z - \bar{z}}{2 \cdot \left| z \right| \cdot i}\\
\frac{\frac{z}{\left| z \right|} - \frac{\left| z \right| \cdot \bar{z}}{\left| z \right|^{2}}}{2 \cdot i} &= \frac{z - \bar{z}}{2 \cdot \left| z \right| \cdot i}\\
\frac{\frac{z}{\left| z \right|} - \frac{\bar{z}}{\left| z \right|}}{2 \cdot i} &= \frac{z - \bar{z}}{2 \cdot \left| z \right| \cdot i}\\
\frac{\frac{z - \bar{z}}{\left| z \right|}}{2 \cdot i} &= \frac{z - \bar{z}}{2 \cdot \left| z \right| \cdot i}\\
\frac{z - \bar{z}}{2 \cdot \left| z \right| \cdot i} &= \frac{z - \bar{z}}{2 \cdot \left| z \right| \cdot i} \qquad \square\\
\end{align*}
$$

NGL: that's kinda cool.

##### Startig With The RHS

$$
\begin{align*}
\text{Formula}\, 1 \quad\mid\quad \sin\left( v \right) &= \frac{z - \bar{z}}{2 \cdot \left| z \right| \cdot i}\\
\sin\left( v \right) &= \frac{\left| z \right| \cdot e^{\arg\left( z \right) \cdot i} - \left| \bar{z} \right| \cdot e^{\arg\left( \bar{z} \right) \cdot i}}{2 \cdot \left| z \right| \cdot i}\\
\text{Formula}\, 4 \quad\mid\quad \sin\left( v \right) &= \frac{\left| z \right| \cdot e^{\arg\left( z \right) \cdot i} - \left| z \right| \cdot e^{\arg\left( \bar{z} \right) \cdot i}}{2 \cdot \left| z \right| \cdot i}\\
\sin\left( v \right) &= \frac{\left| z \right| \cdot e^{\arg\left( z \right) \cdot i} - \left| z \right| \cdot e^{-\arg\left( z \right) \cdot i}}{2 \cdot \left| z \right| \cdot i}\\
\sin\left( v \right) &= \frac{\left| z \right| \cdot \left( e^{\arg\left( z \right) \cdot i} - e^{-\arg\left( z \right) \cdot i} \right)}{2 \cdot \left| z \right| \cdot i}\\
\text{Formula}\, 3 \quad\mid\quad \sin\left( v \right) &= \frac{e^{\arg\left( z \right) \cdot i} - e^{-\arg\left( z \right) \cdot i}}{2 \cdot \left| z \right| \cdot i}\\
\sin\left( v \right) &= \sin\left( \arg\left( z \right) \right)\\
\sin\left( v \right) &= \sin\left( v \right) \qquad \square\\
\end{align*}
$$